# Is a commit a branch in itself ? - git

Tags: git, branch, commit

I hope the following question will not be too general. Plz telle me if not, this post could be migrate elswhere.
So, I have read in this really good [doc](http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf) (bottom of page 10) that a commit could be considered as a branch in itself. In what way could it be said like that ? How does a commit support the whole history of a branch (for mathematics minded people, could a commit be thought as fibration (supporting the history of the so-called branch) over some tree)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's too esoteric a discussion of the "branch" concept, but that's not terribly important.

The effect is that every commit represents a branch whose HEAD is that commit, with the difference from typical branches being that the branch name (which is the SHA-1 of the commit) is immutable. The hash-as-branch-name always points to the hash-as-commit.

Try it yourself with this command: `git checkout 2ae907` (where the reference is to some previous commit). You'll get text like this:

> Note: checking out '2a9e07'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
>   experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
>   you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing
>   another checkout.

Commits are added to a graph of commits, so every commit is the root of a subgraph that includes all the previous history.

Comment: yes but where the data related to the link between one commit to its parent is stored ?

Comment: git implements a Directed Acyclic Graph to store the relationship between commits. How the DAG is implemented isn't important to understanding the abstract notion of how commits are related to one another.

Comment: @Newben: Every commit contains a reference to its parent(s). You can see it with e.g. `git show --format=raw <commitid>` - it will list the ID of the parent commit. Note that a commit may have more than one parent (merge commit), or none (initial commit).

Comment: @Newben: The object format is described in the User's Manual in the [storage format](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#object-details) section and in the [object database](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#the-object-database) section.  That pretty much describes loose objects.  The pack format is described [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/pack-format.txt), and the index format [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/index-format.txt).

Answer (score 1):

In git a commit always includes the complete history of the tree at that point (by including a reference to its parent commit).  In that sense, you can consider it a branch.  The only difference is that a branch has a symbolic name, so that you don't have to refer to it by its hash.

Comment: so if I understood well, each commit stores for each 'file' of it tree a serie of references for successive diff files, the composition of which leads to this 'file' ?

Comment: Not exactly.  If you read [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book), I'm sure you'll be enlightened.

Comment: It would probably be more accurate to say that a commit contains a snapshot of the tree at that point rather than the complete history.  History is pretty much by definition a series of events rather than a single event.